# Crop image in scilab

Tags: scilab

I want to crop image using mouse selection at particular region of interest in scilab,here my code is

```
I=imread('G:\SCI\FRAME\mixer2.jpg');  
   I1G = rgb2gray(I);
   figure();ShowImage(I1G,'mixer');
   IN1G = gca();
   rect1 = rubberbox();
   ROI1=imcrop(I1G,rect1);disp(ROI1);
```

**But it gives the following error: The rectangle is out of the image range.**
and i also use xclick and xgetmouse function for cropping using mouse selection and it also gives the same error.
please give me suggestions for correcting code .

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from the difference between the image coordinate system (used by `imcrop` and all the other functions of the [SIVP toolbox](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/)) and the "regular" coordinate system (used by `rubberbox`, `xcick` and all the builtin functions). Images have the first pixel at top-left. On the contrary `rubberbox` have the zero at bottom left.
To correct this you have to reverse the y (vertical) axes coordinate before applying `imcrop()`:

```
imagefile="d:\Attila\PROJECTS\Scilab\Stackoverflow\mixer_crop.jpg"; 
I=imread(imagefile); 
I1G=rgb2gray(I);
scf(0); clf(0);
ShowImage(I1G,'mixer');
rect1=rubberbox();
imheight=size(I1G,"r");   //image height
rect1(2)=imheight-rect1(2);   //reverse y axes coordinates (0 is at top)
ROI1=imcrop(I1G,rect1);
scf(1); clf(1);
ShowImage(ROI1,'ROI1');
```

Comment: it also gives the following error:- The rectangle is out of the image range(I also tried rect1(2) instead of rect1 in ROI1).

Comment: Try NOT to hit the border of your image with rubberbox, but select only inner points! If you want to select exactly from the sides, you may have to correct the resulting `rect1` coorinates to stay within the image, since your actual click might be outside.

Comment: No, because i want to select region of interest in image.

Comment: For me the above code works perfectly if the selection is inside the image, so I can not reproduce your error. You may try to double check the content of `rect1` or define one manually (not by using `rubberbox`) e.g. `rect1=[50,50,50,50]` and see if `imcrop` fails or not.

Comment: it not work,I want to attach image but this site not permit me and the image is like two inlet or one outlet in which i want to select ROI

Comment: If the problem comes from the `imcrop` function, you may try to write your own function for this: basically you have to extract the selected region from a 2D or 3D matrix: try e.g. `ROI=I1G(50:100,50:100)` or in case of color images: `I1G(50:100,50:100,1:3)`. If you can upload the image somewhere and provide a link to it I may also try it.

Comment: I have upload image at this url:- https://lh4.ggpht.com/hKlzopzakfu2YLvn4qHARFSqw5WyF5DXYXp8dH6tCphuGkEKCO6xQbqV-SW-t1TjdHhqQQ=s100

Comment: I tried with your uploaded files and it works perfectly for me. I edited my answer to contain the full working code. If you still get error with this code, then not the code but your scilab and/or toolbox installation may be faulty. Try to reinstall it, or try a previous version of Scilab. Note: I tested this code in Scilab 5.4.1 64bit. You can have many different Scilab versions installed at the same time.

Comment: Ok, the error was due to gca() command ,why it is?,code is working.

Comment: This code is proper working in windows, but When I run this in UBUNTU ,

Comment: When I run in UBUNTU then it gives the same error -rectangle is out of image range .In windows rect1=[128,27.6,22,26] and in UBUNTU rect1=[-0.583,479,0.0583,0.128] at same position on same figure,Iale check without reverse y coordinate but it gives same error and coordinate system in both OS is same .How can i solve this problem?